# Using jquery to add to create a list via the console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am just trying to bolster my knowledge on jquery...new to javascript.
My question is I am trying to add items a list.

```
$('#items').append('<li>My first item</li>') // the first line worked okay
```

I wrote the above line using the console. I am trying to write the line below in script.js using a text editor

```
function addToList(item) {
'<li>' + item + '</li>'
}
```

I reloaded the index.html in my browser, and tried running the function I have written from the browser console the code below.

```
addToList('build a website');
```

Below is the excerpt of my html code

```
<div id="container">
  <h1>Wish List</h1>
  <ol id="items">
    <!-- Items will be added here -->
  </ol>
  <span class="total"></span>
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="item"/>
  <button id="add-to-list">Add to list</button>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance guys and let me know if I left anything out to get the code working.

Comment: You are only creating a string not appending it to DOM, use `function addToList(item) {
$('#items').append('<li>' + item + '</li>');
}`

Answer (score 3):

use

```
function addToList(item) {
    $('#items').append('<li>' + item + '</li>');
}
```

Comment: ooop...@Satpal beat me to it!

Comment: Yeah, but you posted it as an answer!

Answer (score 2):

There are several things that, I think, you need to do to make the code work the way you had intended:

- As I understand it, you want to add a new list item every time you hit the button (and not necessarily through the console), right ? In that case, you would have to add the "addToList" function to your button.

`<button id="add-to-list" onclick="addToList()">Add to list</button>`

- The problem with your function is that it does not return any value or manipulate a DOM node. The jQuery code to append something to #items should go in there. Hence, I suggest you add a a value selector to the function so that it reads the value of the input field and then appends it to the ordered list
- Lastly, I would add a line to empty out the input field in order to avoid doing so manually every time you add a new list item.

  ```
  function addToList() {
      var newItem = $('#item').val();     
      $('#items').append('<li>' + newItem + '</li>');
      $('#item').val('');    
  }
  ```

  Here is the full snippet:

```js
function addToList() {
 var newItem = $('#item').val();
 $('#items').append('<li>' + newItem + '</li>');
 $('#item').val('');
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</head>


<body>
<div id="container">
  <h1>Wish List</h1>
  <ol id="items">
    <!-- Items will be added here -->
  </ol>
  <span class="total"></span>
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="item"/>
  <button id="add-to-list" onclick="addToList()">Add to list</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

`addToList` currently only evaluates `'<li>' + item + '</li>'` - but does nothing with it.

What you might want to do is change `addToList` to:

```
function addToList(text) {
   return '<li>' + text + '</li>'
}
```

However, that won't actually add the item to the list.

As @Mfoo says, you can do:

```
function addToList(text) {
   return $('#items').append('<li>' + text + '</li>');
}
```

However, you need to be aware that this will not escape any HTML - so calling `addToList("10 < 50") will probably break your page. If that's not a problem, then fine, else:

```
function addToList(text) {
   return $('#items').append($('<li/>').text(text));
}
```